# How to get info of specific iNodes inside Terminal

Tags: terminal

when I type `ls -li` I get all files including their iNode-id. (e.g. 19753844)

How can I now access that specific iNode (so that I see details and the data saved to that iNode)?

I just can't find a command online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get extended info of an existing inode use find:

```
sudo find / -inum $inode -exec ls -ilaO@ {} ";"
```

Replace $inode by the real inode-ID e.g.:

```
sudo find / -inum 1745768 -exec ls -ilaO@ {} ";"
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
1745768 -rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  - 79 13 Nov 12:30 /Users/user/.oracle_jre_usage/613bcfb3a06ef613.timestamp
```

To see the data use the appropriate app or a command line tool (cat, file etc).